# how to check if you are on a certain page in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to know if it is possible if test which page you are on using jquery mobile and based on that page do whatever you need to. Here is the code I was using:

```
if(window.location.href == '#searchpage')
{
    $("#searchtitle").val($(this).attr('titleResult'));
    $("#searchauthor").val($(this).attr('authorResult'));
    $("#searchpublisher").val($(this).attr('publisherResult'));
    $( "#searchedition" ).val($(this).attr('editionResult'));
    $("#searchDetailsSearchResults").empty();
}
```

i.e. if I am on the page called searchpage then we would fill in text boxes with certain values. As such I'm struggling to find a way to determine if I am on a given page? How would I achieve this?

Comment: if(location.hash=="#searchpage"){ ... }

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for `$.mobile.activePage`

```
if $.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "searchpage" // do stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Fetch current url using pure JS:
`var current_url = window.location.pathname;`

Fetch current url using jQuery:
`var current_url = $(location).attr('href');`

If you're looking for the page **title** instead of url:
`var current_title = $(document).attr('title');`

---

Then you would simply use that to check if you're on the expected page:

```
var current_title = $(document).attr('title');
if (current_title == "Home") {
    console.log("on the homepage");
}
```